# PSN Avoiding DLC Region Locking Processes confirmation

Tags: achievements, ps3, psn, ps-vita

From my research, while PS3/PSP/PSV hard copy games (not downloaded from the store) aren't region locked their DLC is locked to the store of the region the game come from,
example, Hyperdimension Neptunia Mk. II brought from the US has DLC which will only work if you buy it from the US Playstation Store and not the EU or JP stores

The whole point to this is having your entire trophy collection assigned to one account regardless of where you brought the game, not out of laziness but rather having a single profitable ID created by Playstation which has your entire trophy collection

I'm doing this under the basis that I want all my trophies on my EU Account while having a US Game with DLC

#### For PS3

1. While not signed in, Run game so that Trophies are installed into system
2. Log into EU PSN Account and Sync Trophies
3. Log out of EU PSN Account
4. Create US PSN Account (using a US Postal Address) and sign in
5. Transfer Funds from visa/master card to PSN Wallet
6. Buy DLC for US Brought Game, Download and Install (the install will occur after the download automatically and can't be canceled when it starts)
7. Sign out of US PSN Account
8. Play Game with DLC (DLC should work weather your online or not, didn't needed to be signed in to play Tales of Graces F DLC)
9. When I want to sync my Trophies again, sign into EU PSN Account and Sync

#### For PSP

Same Process but I don't think there's any PSP game with trophies, I haven't found any

#### For PS Vita

Apparently from what I read the PSN Accounts are bound tot he system so you can't just log out but so a full system restore in order to rebind to a different account

1. While not signed in, Run game so that Trophies are installed into system
2. Log into EU PSN Account and Sync Trophies
3. System Restore system with memory card removed so to avoid an accidentally reformatting of it
4. Create US PSN Account (using a US Postal Address) and sign in
5. Transfer Funds from visa/master card to PSN Wallet
6. Buy DLC for US Brought Game, Download and Install (the install will occur after the download automatically and can't be cancelled when it starts)
7. System Restore system with memory card removed so to avoid an accidentally reformatting of it
8. Play Game with DLC (I don't have a PS Vita but I assume DLC works for it much like the PS3 and you don't need to be online for it)
9. When I want to sync my Trophies again, sign into EU PSN Account and Sync

Now what I asking is confirmation that these work exactly as I have them, if not, please indicate what I need to change, I want it confirmed just in case if I have got it wrong and I can't reverse what I've done, I'm more concerned about the PS3 steps as have a US game which I know will have Trophies with it and I know there's DLC for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've over complicated this.

For PS3, basically once a DLC was installed on a system, any user on that system can play that DLC and earn trophies for it, whether signed in to PSN or not, I've never seen DLC which is only usable by the buying user except for items like Home items, Avatars and DLC for one specific game I know of.

So your "process" is fairly simple:

1. Log into the appropriate store for your game's region (you'll need another PS3 profile with a PSN account in that region)
2. Buy DLC from that store (funds could be from a local credit card or prepaid PSN card) and install it.
3. Log back into your main profile and account and play the DLC.

PSVita is different. A PSVita system and memory card is locked to a single user, so even if you switched the Vita's user (system restore), you'd still be only able to download the DLC to a memory card assigned to the "foreign user", meaning it won't be accessible to your "main user" (which will need its own memory card), this means that in order to buy DLC for a PSVita game, **you must own a copy of the game from the same region as your main PSN user**. There's no current way to avoid this (at least one that I know of), and it basically means any PSVita game that has "required DLC" like online passes, UPlay pass, etc, will only be "fully playable" if you buy games from your own region.

Comment: i only read that the PSVita console was bound to an account and required the process of system restoring it which involves watching some unskippable move again and loosing icon placement (what ever that means), i didn't know the memory card was bound aswell, curious, with a PSVita, can i so a system restore on a PSVita (to bind to a US Account) and use a different memory card to download DLC, restore the system back to an EU account then copy the DLC from one card to the other?

Comment: The locking of cards to a specific account was added in a recent firmware update, so your sources may have been out of date. Even if you do download the DLC into a different card, you can't just copy it to another card, because a. You can't directly access the files on the card (only through PS3/PC backup utility) and b. Those files are probably encrypted, even if you could access them, they probably wouldn't work on a different account, otherwise people would have posted DLC files freely on the internet for everyone to use...

Comment: just to add to the info you provided me, it seems you need to have separate user profiles on the Console, trying to log into a different account on the same user porofile presents you with an error saying you can't log into another user's PSN account, this may be related to the accounts being bound to memory cards with the Vita cause unlike the PS3, the save games would be saved to memory card (while the PS3 saves to the internal Harddrive

Comment: I'll clarify my answer :)